# Publication Id for the DXA Page is unknown

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

We put a line with tcm information in the head section of the html page.

Purpose is that Sitemanager & content people easier can find the page in content manager.

```
<head> 
  <meta name="tcm-info" content="tcm:99-417519-64" />
  ..
```

With DXA, the Publication Id is unknown. Model Id contains only that 417519.

It's possible to make a config value, but is there a value already for Publication Id?

Comment: That's helpful information for editors! If interesting to you or your site manager and content people, consider voting or commenting on this [related idea](https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/textbox-to-allow-a-user-to-paste-a-url-and-the-page-opens-in-tridion-like-a-reverse-lookup) to find items in the CMS by URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any separate configuration for that. In DXA there is a container called Localization to store the requested Publication information.
You can retrieve the publication id from that localization.

Use the below line to get the publication id from your code

```
 WebRequestContext.Localization.Id
```

For more information about the localization you can check [this](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Common/Configuration/Localization.cs) class